# How to use fread() for each struct field separately when reading binary file?

Tags: c, struct, binaryfiles

In my `struct` I've got the fields

```
struct records {
    short link; 
    double gate; 
    unsigned char bar;
    int rest; 
    char rink; 
};
```

And in my `main()`

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    struct records rec;

    if(argc<2){//no paramaters
        //return error
    }

    FILE *fp=fopen(argv[1], "rb");

    if(fp==NULL){//no file
         //return error
    }

    //use fread() for each field in struct separately.   

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

How do you call `fread()` so that it reads each `struct` field separately, then prints them out? I know (every similar sort of question and tut online) shows calling `fread()` by supplying the whole `struct`, but I don't want to do this, eg. `fread(&rec, sizeof(rec), 1, fp)`. I want to read each field separately with its own `fread()` call. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How did you write the file? Can the file be written and read on different machines?

Comment: @taskinoor its for a uni class, so the teacher wrote it. I would assume that he wrote it so that it works across all machines

Comment: You can't read individual fields without knowing in which order they are written. Also if not taken special care of binary files may not be portable (google for little big endian). In order to read those fields correctly you need to know first how they are written.

Comment: Look at `offsetof` in `stddef.h`. (and no, reading and writing structs to binary only works for a given compiler, you can do it on your machine, but don't give the data file to someone and expect them to be able to compile you code with a different compiler and read your file, padding within the struct can vary from compiler to compiler) That's why you should serialize the data before the write and then de-serialize after the read. For your assignment, ignore it, but know you must serialize in the real world, just as it you were sending across a network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fread need two important arguments: a pointer and a length.

You can easily get both:

```
struct records {
    short link; 
    double gate; 
    unsigned char bar;
    int rest; 
    char rink; 
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    struct records rec;

    // ...

    FILE *fp=fopen(argv[1], "rb");

    // ...

    //use fread() for each field in struct separately.   

    while (!feof(fp))
    {
        if (fread(&rec.link, sizeof(rec.link), 1, fp) != 1
           || fread(&rec.gate, sizeof(rec.gate), 1, fp) != 1
           || // etc...
           )
        {
            // error !
        }
        // print the contents of rec, for example...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I sort of used that syntax and got it working. I used `fread(&rec.link, sizeof(rec.link),1,fp)` for each field and then `printf` them all. I now have a new question, which is how to keep rewrite over the struct after printing them? So that I can keep printing new values? Sort of like a loop that stores struct values, prints them, then rewrites the values, and prints again? Should i just post a new question for this?

Comment: You can create a list to store new records as you read them, or keep them in a dynamic array.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on the dynamic array? And if possible what do you mean by creating a list to store new records? Thanks

Comment: If you just want to print one record at a time, you can simply loop over the entire file, like you would if you were reading by record..

Comment: Using your `while(!feof(fp))` and various other `while` and `eof`s, it prints out the data, but always repeats the last line. So it ends every output with the last line twice. Why is it doing this? I find it wierd because its not outputting every line twice, just the last one.

Comment: IYou should ask another question and post your code.  There is no way I can guess why.

Answer (score -1):

I'm late, but this might be useful.

You can do this with the help of `offsetof()` function.

Padding bytes are involved here.

`sizeof(struct records)` is `32` bytes in my machine (but that can be different of different machines).

Yet the combined size of all the members of a `struct record` variable is only 
`sizeof(short)+sizeof(double)+sizeof(unsigned char)+sizeof(int)+sizeof(char)` which on my machine should be `16` bytes (assuming `short`, `double`, `unsigned char`, `int` & `char` occupy 2, 8, 1, 4 & 1 bytes respectively).

This is because of something called padding bytes. You can read about this [here](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/#_structure_alignment_and_padding). This is done to make things easier for the processor.

So as per these sizes,

a `struct record` would be like

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
|    link(2)     |                 6 bytes                     |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|                         gate (8)                             |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|  bar(1)  |      3 bytes      |            rest(4)            |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|  rink(1) |                7 bytes                            |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

First find the point from where each member of the `struct` starts

```
printf("link: %d\n", offsetof(struct records, link));
printf("gate: %d\n", offsetof(struct records, gate));
printf("bar: %d\n", offsetof(struct records, bar));
printf("rest: %d\n", offsetof(struct records, rest));
printf("rink: %d\n", offsetof(struct records, rink));
```

this prints

```
link: 0
gate: 8
bar: 16
rest: 20
rink: 24
```

You can use this method to find how the structure members are packed in your machine.

What you need to do now is read the required data while disregarding the padding bytes.

Let's create a structure variable `a`.

```
fread(&a.link, sizeof(a.link), 1, fp);
fseek(fp, 6, 1); //move the file pointer by 6 bytes from current position to avoid the padding bytes

fread(&a.gate, sizeof(a.gate), 1, fp);
fread(&a.bar, sizeof(a.bar), 1, fp);
fseek(fp, 3, 1); //move the file pointer to avoid the 3 bytes

fread(&a.rest, sizeof(a.rest), 1, fp);
fread(&a.rink, sizeof(a.rink), 1, fp);
```

Now you can use the values in `a`.

I didn't know how to do it when you asked the previous question. But I did a bit of reading and found a way. Since you posted a separate question I thought it would be better to post an answer here.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy If `%zu` is used instead, will it be right?

Comment: Sorry. I misread.  Your talk about offsetof is not related to the original question.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy I got this from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_macro_offsetof.htm. The example prints offsets like that.

Comment: It's just not related to the question.